# Unit test for Spring controller have RequestPart String param

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I must write unit test using junit for a spring web project.
A controller have parameter like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)  
public ResponseEntity<String> unlock(
    @PathVariable String id, @RequestPart String param)
```

I dont know what exactly param receive. I usually use @RequestPart MultipartFile.

Comment: Do you need a unit or integration test. If it is a unit test just call the method.

Comment: Now I write unit test like
         result = this.mockMvc
                .perform(put("/v1/tasks/" + id)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json)
                .with(httpBasic('demo', 'demo')))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    It is ok for test result. How can I test file upload correctly

Answer (score 0):

1. In the test, Inject your class.

   2. Add [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server)  (is a part of Spring Test an let you call your WS).
   3. Prepare the mock, ie: `when(myClassInjected.myMethod()).thenReturn(the_result);`
   4. Perform a call with MockMvc. (you can follow the tutorial at the end of the post)
   5. Verify the call, ie: `verify(myClassInjected, times(1)).myMethod();`

Check [this](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/) tutorial to get more information.